# Strange behaviour when requesting on a ManyToMany relation with composite PrimaryKey

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, composite-key

I am trying to create a ManyToMany relation between DocumentModels, with an additionnal information in the relation (dosIndex)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_DOCUMENT_MODELS_DMO")
public class TDocumentModelsDmo extends fr.axigate.nx.frontend.server.common.entity.ValidityPeriodEntity implements Serializable
{

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "T_DOCUMENT_MODELS_DMO_DMOID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "T_DMO_ID_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "T_DOCUMENT_MODELS_DMO_DMOID_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name = "DMO_ID", precision = 22)
    private Long                        dmoId;

    //Other unrelated members, no reference to TjDocumentSourcesDos
    //constructors, getters and setters without annotations
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TJ_DOCUMENT_SOURCES_DOS")
public class TjDocumentSourcesDos implements Serializable
{
    @Column(name = "DOS_INDEX", nullable = false, precision = 22)
    private long                    dosIndex; //the additionnal info on the relation

    @EmbeddedId
    private TjDocumentSourcesDosPK  id                  = new TjDocumentSourcesDosPK();

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("dosParentId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "DOS_PARENT_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private TDocumentModelsDmo      TDocumentModelsDmoParent;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("dosSourceId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "DOS_SOURCE_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private TDocumentModelsDmo      TDocumentModelsDmoSource;

    //constructors, getters and setters without annotations
}

@Embeddable
public class TjDocumentSourcesDosPK implements Serializable
{
    @Column(name = "DOS_PARENT_ID", nullable = false, precision = 22)
    private Long                dosParentId;

    @Column(name = "DOS_SOURCE_ID", nullable = false, precision = 22)
    private Long                dosSourceId;

    //constructors, getters and setters without annotations
    //hashCode and equals implemented
}
```

I can insert datas in both tables, but when I try to request it using an entityManager, i get something strange :

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT dos.TDocumentModelsDmoSource  FROM TDocumentModelsDmo AS dmo, TjDocumentSourcesDos as dos WHERE dmo.dmoId = :modelId AND dos.TDocumentModelsDmoParent = dmo");
query.setParameter("modelId", someData);
ArrayList<TjDocumentSourcesDos> dosList = (ArrayList<TjDocumentSourcesDos>) query.getResultList();
```

will work, while the following will throw an exception : `QuerySyntaxException: dos.TDocumentModelsDmoSource is not mapped`

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT sources FROM TDocumentModelsDmo AS dmo, TjDocumentSourcesDos as dos, dos.TDocumentModelsDmoSource AS sources WHERE dmo.dmoId = :modelId AND dos.TDocumentModelsDmoParent = dmo");
query.setParameter("modelId", someData);
ArrayList<TjDocumentSourcesDos> dosList = (ArrayList<TjDocumentSourcesDos>) query.getResultList();
```

This prevents me from doing more complicated requests where I would use my `sources` models in the WHERE condition.

I tried adding a `referencedColumnName = "DMO_ID"` in both my JoinColumn annotations, but I still get the same error